# What happens when you claim a PosPrinter using Microsoft Point of Serivce & Epson OPOS for.net then computer unexpectedly shutdown?

Tags: c#, point-of-sale, epson, opos, pos-for-.net

What happens when you claim a PosPrinter using Microsoft Point of Serivce & Epson OPOS for.net then computer unexpectedly shutdown? does your PosPrinter get broken? or does the library manage this already?

Comment: Breaking a POS printer requires hardware.  A hammer.  You can't break it with a software lock.

Answer (score 0):

Since the lock is only in the software drivers, and only in memory, once the PC is shutdown the lock is gone.